# Python list maze

Tags: python, list, maze

Hi I am a beginner in python, I keep having "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'maze'"
in my problem I cannot find the problem on my own so please someone help me.
Here is the code.

```py
def valid(n,maze,x,y):
    if maze[x][y] == 1 and x < n  and y < n:
        return True
    else : 
        return False

def marked(n,maze,x,y):
    if valid(n,maze,x - 1,y) == True:
        x = x -1
        y += 1
        move(n,maze,x,y)
    elif valid(n,maze,x,y - 1) == True:
        y = y - 1
        x += 1
        move(n,maze,x,y)
    else:
        print("Error")

        
def move(n,maze,x,y):
    #Since Goal == x = n - 1, y= n - 1(maze[n - 1][ n - 1]).
    if  x == n -1 and  y == n-1 :
        print(maze)
    else:
        if x < n:
            x += 1
        if x > n:
            y += 1
        if valid(n,maze,x,y) == True:
            move(n,maze,x,y)
        elif valid(n,maze,x,y) == False:
            marked(n,maze,x,y)


maze = [[1, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1]]
move(4,maze,0,0)
```

Comment: your line `marked(n.maze,x,y)`  should be `marked(n, maze, x, y)`  (comma instead of dot)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a typo in this block:

```
    if valid(n,maze,x,y) == True:
            move(n,maze,x,y)
        elif valid(n,maze,x,y) == False:
            marked(n.maze,x,y)
```

Specifically:

```
marked(n.maze,x,y)
```

Needs to be

```
marked(n, maze,x,y)
```

It needs to be a coma  otherwise it is interpreted as:

object **n** with attribute **maze**.

but you want it to be:

first parameter **n **,****

second parameter **maze**